# Adding custom user options to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, gravatar

I am trying to add a custom field to the wordpress user profile page. For instance if I wanted to add a field where the user could put in their Linkedin, or Twitter user name, then use that value whenever the user posts a comment, or if the user is an author, to add that value in their posts.

I have a forum (bbpress) integrated so I would also like to use this value to customize the users avatar in the forums.

I am looking at the way Wordpress uses Gravatar. I would like to do something similar. However, I'm not sure where to start. I've written a couple of shortcode plugins in the past, but nothing this complicated.

Anyone have any ideas on where I should begin on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this [post](http://blog.themeforest.net/wordpress/create-an-options-page-for-your-wordpress-theme/) and [this](http://wpshout.com/create-an-advanced-options-page-in-wordpress/)